# How to save Flickr images to files on Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am getting a photosets from flickr anyone know how to save or export an image to file on iphone afer getting pics from flickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save a photo to the camera roll call the function:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil);  //myImage is a UIImage
```

Provide nil for the last three arguments unless you want to be notified of when the image has finished saving.  In this case, the arguments and their types are:

```
UIImage  *image,
id       completionTarget,
SEL      completionSelector,
void     *contextInfo
```

More details of this function are in the [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: thnx dude ...i gona to check this n hope it wil help me

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to store the images offline on the device? You could save it into the documents directory of your app on the device.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImageName.png"];

//Assume you have the imageData from the url connection you used to downlod
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: thnx bt i want to save it into iphone photo gallery so we can use(set) it as background